# Android, LogCat shows this error: "Deprecated Thread methodes are not supported", What is this?

Tags: android, multithreading, deprecated, ddms

After running the program, Logcat shows some errors (picture).
But after that program runs and works without a problem. I can't understand where the problem is.

After running the program, Screen-shot will show for 5 seconds and after that menu (That the activity name is Scroll_View) will show. Now, LogCat shows error.
However, when I click on each button, it works fine without crass or anything else.

Is it important?

This is the code of thread:

```
protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 5000;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
            Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int waited = 0;
                        while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                            sleep(100);
                            if(_active) {
                                waited += 100;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    } finally {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent("mobilesoft.asia.malaysia_directory.SplashScreen.Scroll_View"));
                        stop();
                    }
                }
            };
            splashTread.start();
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You receive this exception because Thread's methods [`stop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) and [`stop(Throwable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29) are deprecated and should never be used.

> Because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state.

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot indicates that you are calling Thread.stop() in the class SplashScreen.java (line 35). `Thread.stop()` has been deprecated for a while, because they are old, unsafe and can have negative effects on the JVM (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), and apparently the Dalvik VM doesn't support those thread methods any more. You should be able to replace the `Thread.stop()` call with something else - the link has some pretty good example on how you should do instead of calling those methods.